# Isomorphism of fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Find an isomorphism from the quotient field $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ to the field $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]=\{a+b\sqrt{2}\ |\ a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$

Having a lot of trouble figuring this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^2-2$, which is irreducible over $\Bbb Q[x]$ by Eisenstein $p=2$. Hence
$\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle$ is a field.

We have $\alpha = x+ \langle x^2-2\rangle $ is a root of $f(x)$, as I had shown in another of your [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1571945/229882)(posted after this).

This means that $f(x)$ has a root in $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$(actually both), these roots are $\pm \sqrt{2}$ as you can show, and so $\Bbb Q(\alpha)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$. Kroneckers theorem says that $Q(\alpha)$ is a $2$-dimensional $\Bbb Q$-vectorspace with basis $\{1,\alpha\} = \{1,\sqrt{2}\}$ and hence $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}) = \{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\Bbb Q\}$.

Now you should be able to think about Cameron's answer.

---

It turns out $\Bbb Q(\alpha)=\Bbb Q[\alpha]$. Since $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ is a field it has elements like $\frac{1}{1+\alpha}$, but they can always be simplified back to looking like an element of $\Bbb Q[\alpha]$, since $(1+\sqrt{2})(a+b\sqrt{2})=1\implies a+b\sqrt{2}+a\sqrt{2}+2b=a+2b+(a+b)\sqrt{2}=1$

Since we are in the basis $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$, we must have $a=-b$ so $a=-1,b=1$. $(1+\sqrt{2})(-1+\sqrt{2})=-1+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}+2=1$

Hence $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}=-1+\sqrt{2}$.

---

$$\psi:\Bbb Q[x]\to \Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}], \psi: f(x)\mapsto f(\sqrt{2})$$

By the division algorithm, you can see this is essentially:

$f(x)= (x^2-2)q(x) + r(x)$ where $f(x)\in \Bbb Q[x]$, but with $f(x) + \langle x^2-2\rangle \in \Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle$ we have $f(x) = 0+r(x) = ax+b$ ($a,b\in\Bbb Q$) so when we take $\phi:f(x)\mapsto f(\alpha)$ we have $a\sqrt{2}+b$

---

So hopefully it would be enlightening to look at:

$$a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0$$

Evaluate at $x=\sqrt{2}$

$$a_n(\sqrt{2})^n+ \cdots + a_0 = b_2\sqrt{2}+b_0$$

(since $\sqrt{2}^2=2$, $\sqrt{2}^3 = 2\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{2}^4 = 4$ etc, i.e. it always reduces to $a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\Bbb Q$)

Comment: So what would the actual isomorphism look like? I know $<x^2-2>$ will be in the kernal, but can't seem to construct one that fits this criteria.

Comment: @user139985 See edit, hopefully its clear

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint which should help you figure it out: $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ is made up of linear combinations of elements of the form $[1]$ and $[x]$. (Why are there no higher powers?) What would $(a[1]+b[x])(c[1]+d[x])$ look like in this quotient field? This should make it clear how to construct the isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

You can define $a+b\sqrt{2}\iff bx+a$.